# Linux SUSE - How to clean up PATH?

Tags: linux, path, cleanup

By doing an echo when I am logged in as root I can see I have a lot of junk in my PATH (probably from running tests and then forgetting all about it).

What's the best way to clean it up? I am not looking for anything fancy -- is there a .profile file I can edit? If so, which one (there's too many and I am a newbie!).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok deleting the lines from `bash_profile` did the trick!